# How to prevent the default click behavior on a mudblazor expansion panel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

Currently building out a mudblazor page with multiple expansion panels. I only want the panel to expand if the url contains the id of the panel in the hash of the url. That currently works, however when you click the panel it does this thing where it tries to expand, closes immediately, then notices the url and expands. It looks janky and laggy. Is there a way to prevent that default behavior and only expand using my code, even on click.

The expansion component

```
...
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

@code
{
   ...

    [Parameter]
    public Action<string> SwitchActiveTab {get; set;}
    private void InvokeSwitchActiveTab(string id) => SwitchActiveTab.Invoke(id);
    private bool _isExpanded;
    private bool _isDisabled;
    private string href;
    List<Func<Task>> AfterRenderAsyncJobs = new();
    ...

    private async Task ScrollToNextQuestion() 
    {
        var nextQuestion = assessment.AssessmentQuestions.FirstOrDefault( x=> x.Completed == false && x.ID > question.ID);
        if(nextQuestion != null && nextQuestion.Section == question.Section )
        {
            var selector = $"{nextQuestion.ID}";
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollIntoView", selector, true);
        }
        else if(nextQuestion!= null && nextQuestion.Section != question.Section)
        {
            SwitchActiveTab(nextQuestion.Section);
            var selector = $"{nextQuestion.ID}";
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollIntoView", selector, true);
        }

    }

    private async Task ScrollToQuestion() 
    {
        var selector = $"{question.ID}";
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollIntoView", selector, true);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {     
        href = $"#{question.ID}";
        AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Add(SwitchTabsAndScroll);
        NavManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
    }

    private async Task SwitchTabsAndScroll() 
    {
        var uri = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("returnHref");
        if(uri.Contains('#'))
        {
            var q = assessment.AssessmentQuestions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == uri.Split('#')[1]);
            if(q != null)
            {
                SwitchActiveTab(q.Section);
            }
            if(question.ID == q.ID)
            {
                 _isExpanded = true;
                AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Add(ScrollToQuestion);
            }           
        }
    }



    private void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = NavManager.Uri.ToString();
        if(uri.Contains('#') && uri.Split('#')[1] != question.ID.ToString() && _isExpanded)
        {
             _isExpanded = false;
              StateHasChanged();

        }
        if(uri.Contains('#') && uri.Split('#')[1] == question.ID.ToString() && !_isExpanded)
        {           
             _isExpanded = true;
              StateHasChanged();
        }      
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) 
    {
        while (AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Any()) 
        {
            var job = AfterRenderAsyncJobs.First();
            AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Remove(job);
            await job.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // remove from the NavigationManager event
        NavManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
    }
 
  }
   
   <MudExpansionPanel  id="@question.ID" IsExpanded="@_isExpanded" HideIcon="true" >
        <TitleContent>            
            <AnchorLink href="@href"  disabled="@_isDisabled">
               <MudElement Class="d-flex justify-space-between align-center" >
                   ...
               </MudElement>
            </AnchorLink>
        </TitleContent>
        <ChildContent>
            ...
        
        </ChildContent>
   </MudExpansionPanel>
```

The anchor link component:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Threading.Tasks;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;

@code
    {
        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
        public IDictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = null!;

        [Inject]
        protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; } = null!;

        private string targetId = string.Empty;
        private bool preventDefault = true;

        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            if (Attributes.ContainsKey("href"))
            {
                var href = $"{Attributes["href"]}";
                if (href.StartsWith("#"))
                {
                    targetId = href[1..];
                    preventDefault = true;
                }
            }
            base.OnParametersSet();
        }

        private async Task AnchorOnClickAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetId))
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
                    "scrollIntoView",
                    targetId, false
                );
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

<a @attributes="Attributes"
   @onclick="AnchorOnClickAsync"
   @onclick:preventDefault="@preventDefault">
    @ChildContent
</a>
```

and the vanilla js scripts:

```
 function scrollIntoView(elementId, fromComplete) {
        debugger
        let elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (elem ) {
            elem.id = "tmp"
            window.location.hash = elementId;
            elem.id = elementId
            if (fromComplete) {
                 const elementRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            const absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top + window.pageYOffset;
            const middle = absoluteElementTop - (window.innerHeight / 2) + 150;
            window.scrollTo(0, middle);
            }

           
        }
         
    }

    function returnHref(){
      
        return window.location.href
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code I would suggest to use the [Disabled parameter](https://mudblazor.com/api/expansionpanel#pages) for the expansion panel to disable the clicks. When the URL contains the data you want, you can switch the disabled to false and let the default behaviour do it's job. The check happens than before the click-event is fired.

Unless this doesn't work in your business case. Do let me know.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for confirming!